# Stop highlighting parentheses when I start typing

Tags: highlighting, parentheses

I use `(show-paren-mode 1)` to get help seeing where parentheses are. I have `(setq show-paren-delay 2)` to prevent intrusive highlighting when I don't need it. This is how it works now:

1. Put cursor on a parenthesis. After 2 seconds, both parentheses highlight
2. Use cursor keys. Highlighting stays on as long as I keep cursoring.
3. Stop moving around. Highlighting eventually disappears, after 2 seconds.

It *should* work like this:

1. Same as above.
2. Use cursor keys. *Highlighting disappears immediately!*

The rationale is that I need highlighting as an aide to find the matching parenthesis, or to detect imbalance. Once I've established this, the highlighting is no longer useful and I want it gone.

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe to describe what you're seeing and what you want to see instead.

Comment: @Drew: See updated post.

Comment: Do you see that when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? I don't. I don't see any such delay. If the cursor is moved away from a paren the highlighting ceases immediately, for me. If you don't see the problem without your init file, bisect the file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew OP already put the settings needed to reproduce: `(setq show-paren-delay 2) (show-paren-mode 1)`. The problem, as far as I can tell, is that `show-paren-delay` applies not only to the paren highlighting (which is what OP wants, I guess), but also to the *unhighlighting*.

Comment: @npostavs: Is there a bug or enhancement request here? (If so, OP should `M-x report-emacs-bug`.) If not, is it not OK for OP to just remove that delay customization?

Comment: @Drew: Rewrote the question to make things clearer. Please advice me how I can configure Emacs to my liking, or if this is a bug / feature request.

Comment: Regarding the PS, highlighting for close parens activates when the cursor is *after* the close paren.

Comment: @npostavs: This is so non-intuitive that I didn't even notice it. What is the history behind this design?

Comment: I don't know the history, but I find it fairly intuitive when the delay is set low (the default), then you see the paren you just typed highlighted along with its match.

Comment: @npostavs: Ah! That must be the explanation. However, one would wonder if the behaviour should be different when cursoring over existing parentheses than when typing a new one. I seem to remember that this is how it works in some other editor. Anyway, hope someone can answer the main question, because that one quite puzzles me.

Comment: "if the behaviour should be different when cursoring over existing parentheses than when typing a new one" - that sounds horribly confusing.

Comment: @npostavs: OK, Sublime Text actually does like Emacs, so I agree! But I noticed it even highlights when the cursor is in *any position between the brackets*. Is this possible in Emacs?

Comment: Maybe some of the packages mentioned in https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParenthesesAppearance would be helpful for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It should work like this: [...] Use cursor keys. Highlighting disappears immediately!
>
> I want `show-paren-delay` only when navigating the code. If I actually type a new parenthesis, I want immediate highlighting.

You can make it work like that with the following code.  `show-paren-clear-highlight` should be added to Emacs since it's accessing internal variables.

```el
(defun show-paren-clear-highlight ()
  "Turn off any previous paren highlighting."
  (delete-overlay show-paren--overlay)
  (delete-overlay show-paren--overlay-1))

;; Instead of relying on `delsel', you could use
;; `before-change-functions' to detect insertions.  That might be more
;; reliable, but also more complicated.
(require 'delsel)
(defun my-show-paren-update-on-insert ()
  ;; A command with `delete-selection' property probably inserts text.
  (if (get this-command 'delete-selection)
      (show-paren-function)
    (show-paren-clear-highlight)))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'my-show-paren-update-on-insert)
```

Comment: I noticed something: I want `show-paren-delay` only when navigating the code. If I actually type a new parenthesis, I want immediate highlighting. How do I do this? (The reason I use `show-paren-delay` in the first place is to avoid this insane flickering of parenthesis when I cursor around in my code, but when I'm typing a parenthesis, I obviously want to see the matching parenthesis immediately to know my scoping is correct.)

Comment: @forthrin Updated. Not sure what you mean by "insane flickering" though. Maybe the double-buffering in Emacs 26 would help you more?

Comment: If you cursor down the first column of your `.emacs`, which usually has a lot of opening parenthesis, all the closing parentheses on the end of the line will blink quickly on and off as you pass them. This is not desirable. PS! I couldn't get your new snippet to work.

Comment: @forthin While I'm holding down `C-n` the parens don't get highlighted even with the default delay (`0.125`). If you are trying the new snippet in the same session as the old one, you need to `(remove-hook 'post-command-hook #'show-paren-clear-highlight)`.

Comment: I noticed instant highlighting when typing happens for `lisp-mode`, but not for `php-mode` and `c-mode`. Can you check this?

Comment: @forthrin Oh, it's because they bind `)` to `c-electric-paren` instead of `self-insert-command`, updated.